# How do I change the math italic font in XeTeX/fontspec?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, fontspec, italic

I have a document where the main font is Gotham Book.  So in my preamble I have:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gotham Book}
```

As the fontspec manual describes, this sets the math roman font to also be Gotham Book.  But the math *italic* font remains from the Computer Modern family.

I know that `\setmathrm` will change the math roman font, and there are cousins `\setmathtt`, `\setmathsf`, and `\setboldmathrm`.  But there's no `\setmathit`.

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems that `mathspec` is replaced by `unicode-math`. commands like `\setmathrm` are very limited.

Comment: @Leo mathspec still has its place. unicode-math goes a little overboard with assuming that you actually *have* a unicode maths font.

Comment: A plain LaTeX solution: The [`mathastext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) package.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you do not wish to otherwise change your maths symbols, the best solution is to use the `mathspec` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts(Digits,Latin){Georgia}
\begin{document}
Hello $a+\mathrm{b}=c$
\end{document}
```

Here, Georgia will be used for the body text and `\mathrm`, and Georgia Italic will be used for the italic math glyphs.

The `unicode-math` package (which I kinda wrote) can also do this, but it's somewhat overkill for your purposes and has the additional downside that you need to also load a Unicode mathematics font. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{Georgia Italic}
\begin{document}
Hello $a+b=c$
\end{document}
```

Note that mathspec will not run (yet) on LuaTeX, so if you need a LuaLaTeX solution then you'll need to use `unicode-math` for now.

Comment: Thanks, @Will.  Do I not need `\setmathrm` as well?  It seems like with my Gotham Book example where the main font is sans serifed it didn't change the operator font without it.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, `\setmathrm` is probably a good idea as well, but that's not what your original question at the top of the page asks `:)`

Comment: `\setmainfont` with `fontspec` was changing the math roman font automatically.  I didn't mention it because it was doing the thing I wanted anyway, and I was not aware of `mathspec`.  But `\setmainfont` with `mathspec` does *not* change the math roman font without an additional call to `\setmathrm`.

Comment: @Will I am using the code `\usepackage{mathspec}` along with `\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Latin Modern Math}`. Strangely all the characters present inside the math environment are not italicized. Can you please help me fix this? [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/628677/203675) is my question.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Will and Leo for pointing out the [`mathspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) package.  So now I use:

```
\usepackage{mathspec} %loads fontspec as well
\setmainfont{Gotham Book}
\setmathrm{Gotham Book}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin){Gotham Book}
```

This snippet may need optimization, but works.

Comment: I was 19 seconds too slow `:)`

Answer (score 5):

### The Literal Answer

As of 2019, `fontspec` should find the bold and italic fonts, and load `\mathrm`, `\mathbf` and `\mathit` when you `\setmathrm`.

If you need additional set-up for `\mathit`, the `ItalicFont` and `ItalicFeatures` options of `\setmathrm` set up `\mathit`, just as the `Boldfont` and `BoldFeatures` options set up `\mathbf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathrm{TeX Gyre Schola}[
  ItalicFeatures = {Color = green}]

\begin{document}
Text \textit{italic} \(\mathrm{math}\) \(\mathit{italic}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Schola sample]

### What You Also Might Have Meant

In practice, someone asking about how to set the `\mathit` alphabet likely means the alphabet used for `$x$`.

To set that, you want to load the `unicode-math` package, set a math font that matches your main font and then, if necessary, add a line such as

```
\setmathfont[range=it]{Gotham Book Italic}
```

You can do likewise for `up`, `bfup`, `bfit` and the other math alphabets.

In `unicode-math`, you would normally use `\symit`, `\symup`, etc. for individual letters used as variables, and `\mathit`, `\mathrm`, `\mathup`, etc. for complete words.  However, you can give a package option to interpret `\mathit` as `\symit` and make migrated code compile correctly.