# Using one font type for text, and other type for Math

Tags: fonts

Can I make in my document so that I use one font for the text part, but other font for formulas?

I'd like to use Garamond for text, and Utopia for math.

Comment: Have a look at the solution of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11058/how-do-i-change-the-math-italic-font-in-xetex-fontspec, it should give you the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't help as it requires XeTeX, and I keep getting errors :\

Comment: You didn't say that xeTeX wasn't an option... :-)

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that, sorry :|

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea: the two fonts are quite different from each other, so they don't mix at all.

Comment: But, the equations in garamond are kinda too 'swirly', the equations in utopia look better than the ones in garamond imo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}` or `\usepackage{fourier}` to get Utopia, and `\usepackage[osf]{garamondx}` to obtain Garamond in the text. It is also possible to load `ebgaramond`.

To use `garamondx` package you have to install it through [getnonfreefonts](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) script. And here you have the exact way to do obtain `garamond`: [Can I install fonts from CTAN using TeX Live Utility?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47491/can-i-install-fonts-from-ctan-using-tex-live-utility/47504#47504) (you just have to substitute `garamond` for `garamondx` in the last command).

By the way, as a temporal solution, you can just use this (which just uses the `mathdesign`s garamond)

```
\usepackage{fourier}% or \usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{mdugm}
```

But I encourage using `garamondx` as it adds small caps, old style figures and ligatures.

Comment: This `garamondx` gives me error (.sty not found), and if I use my current one `\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}` with `fourier` the equations end up being messed up :\

Comment: Ouch, I forgot. You have to install them through [getnonfreefonts](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: And I'm on windows... if that's any help xD

Comment: @dingo_d I don't know how to use it in Windows, by the way, I added a *not quite good* solution.