# In XeLaTeX, how do you write upright serif text in math mode after setting the default font to a sans font?

Tags: fonts, xetex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{Bluefox}$ Bluefox
\end{document}
```

Produces two "Bluefox"s that look identical and are in Latin Modern Sans. I basically want to redefine `\mathrm`, but doing so doesn't seem to work. I've also tried importing a font with `\newfontfamily` (Latin Modern Roman) and using that in math mode but it only works outside of math mode.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11058/how-do-i-change-the-math-italic-font-in-xetex-fontspec can give you some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set \mathrm to another font like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{Bluefox}$ Bluefox
\end{document}
```

[image]