# How to get mathit font to match $x$ (using Computer Modern) when main font is different?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, math-fonts

I'm setting a book with main text font Source Serif Pro while sticking with Computer Modern math font.  (Those may not be the best choices, but for the time being, I am stuck with them.)  But `\mathit` is not behaving as I hope.  I want `$v$` and `$\mathit{vs}$` to look compatible, but instead they look startlingly different.

[image: demonstration of wildly different v's]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Singular $v$, plural $\mathit{vs}$, list \texttt{(cons $v$ $\mathit{vs}$)}.
\end{document}
```

I have found the question
[How do I change the math italic font in XeTeX/fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11058/how-do-i-change-the-math-italic-font-in-xetex-fontspec/497909#497909)
and I have poked at the documentation for the `mathspec` and `fontspec` packages, and `fontspec` preserves the Computer Modern symbols just as I had hoped.  How can I tell `\mathit` that I want it to do the same thing it did under Computer Modern?

Comment: even in cm I wouldn't use `$\mathit{vs}$` as the plural of `$v$`,  `\mathit` is the text italic font, used in math, not the math italic font, so `$v$s` would be better markup.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle $\mathit{vs}$ is meant to be a metavariable with a two-letter name, not a plural of $v$.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the no-math option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Singular $v$, plural $\mathit{vs}$, list \texttt{(cons $v$ $\mathit{vs}$)}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: answers the question, but `$v$s` is still better markup for the plural of `$v$` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't look at the meaning at all ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle vs is actually a metavariable that stands for a list of values, not a plural of v.